# Display cash payment for some user group magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to enable or display the cash payment just for some user goup. User group ="A" for exemple ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a custom extension with the `Magento Event/Observer`

config file

```
 <?xml version = "1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Package_Cashondelivery>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Package_Cashondelivery>
    </modules>

    <events>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Package_Cashondelivery_model_observer</class>
                    <method>filterpaymentmethod</method>
                </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>

</config>
```

observer.php

```
class Package_Cashondelivery_Model_Observer {

    public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        /* call get payment method */
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $role = "Retailer"; // you can create an array if there are multiple group
        /*   get  Quote  */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        /* Disable Your payment method for   adminStore */


        if ($role == "Retiler") { // check with in_array for multiple group
            $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $result->isAvailable = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution active all payment methods and that's not what I want!

So I found the solution for those that want to enable a cash payment for a user group.

/app/etc/modules/Amir_ActiveCashPaiement.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amir_ActiveCashPaiement>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Payment/>
            </depends>
        </Amir_ActiveCashPaiement>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Amir/ActiveCashPaiement/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Amir_ActiveCashPaiement>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Amir_ActiveCashPaiement>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <Amir_ActiveCashPaiement>
            <class>Amir_ActiveCashPaiement_Model</class>
        </Amir_ActiveCashPaiement>
    </models>
    <events>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <Amir_ActiveCashPaiement>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Amir_ActiveCashPaiement/Observer</class>
                    <method>paymentMethodIsActive</method>
                </Amir_ActiveCashPaiement>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
</global>

</config>
```

/app/code/local/Amir/ActiveCashPaiement/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Amir_ActiveCashPaiement_Model_Observer
{
    public function paymentMethodIsActive($observer)
    {
        $instance = $observer->getMethodInstance();
        $result = $observer->getResult();

        $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
      //Get customer Group name
        $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);

         //get the name of method payment cashondelivery
        if ($instance->getCode() == "cashondelivery") {
            if ($group->getCode()== "yourgroupname") {
                $result->isAvailable = true;
            } else {
                $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

//think to disable the cash paiement in the backend,
and this module will active this method when the user group log.

?>
```